# Does starting a sentence with "it is" make it passive?

Tags: passive-voice

Suppose I say:

> It is foolish to lick a metal pole.

Is this in the passive voice?

Would this sentence be better as:

> To lick a metal pole is foolish.

How about:

> Licking a metal pole is foolish.

Comment: None of your three sentences is passive.

Comment: Passive: *A metal pole being licked is foolish.* For this case, all three of your suggested sentences are much better than the passive voice.

Answer (score 2):

The passive is very simple. You take the forms of to be + as special complement the past participle.

- Active: The soldiers destroyed the bridge.
- Passive: The bridge was destroyed (by the soldiers).

The passive conjugation is (I give only the forms of the third person singular):

- Simple tenses

is destroyed, was destroyed, will be destroyed, would be destroyed.

- Perfect tenses

has been destroyed, had been destroyed, will have been destroyed, would have been destroyed.

You can form continuous forms by using "being" before the past participle:

The bridge was being destroyed (when we arrived).

http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/activepassive.html